# Getting "double precision not supported on this device" error when trying to run a program using OpenCL in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, c++, opencl

I am trying to run a C++ program on my laptop with ubuntu 18.04, it compiles but I get an error when I try to run it in the terminal.

The program uses OpenCL because I am trying to learn how to use it. I installed OpenCl using the following:

```
sudo apt install ocl-icd-libopencl1   
sudo apt install opencl-headers   
sudo apt install clinfo   
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev   
sudo apt install beignet
```

When I try to run a sample code I got this error:

```
ASSERTION FAILED: Double precision not supported on this device (if this is a literal, use '1.0f' not '1.0')  
  at file /build/beignet-Bevceu/beignet-1.3.2/backend/src/backend/gen_insn_selection.cpp, function void gbe::ConvertInstructionPattern::convertBetweenFloatDouble(gbe::Selection::Opaque&, const gbe::ir::ConvertInstruction&, bool&) const, line 6227  
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

This is a sample code my professor wrote last semester when we were learning how to use OpenCL on the school computers we were given. The code worked there now I am trying to get it to work on my computer but I get this error.

My laptop doesn't have a GPU but has integrated graphics with an Intel® Core™ i5-3210M Processor.

Any help with what this error means or how I can fix it would be great.

Comment: It could simply be true, what the error message is saying: your graphics card only supports single precision, while the computers at your school had fancier graphics cards that also supported double precision. Perhaps you could try some other sample code, that does not use double precision?

Comment: @Elias, what exactly does it mean by double precision?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format